# filter using Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to know how to add a filter to my table, using angular material, I would like the filter to filter through all columns and rows, any help would be greatly appreciated, thnx and good day :D

```
  <table class="table table-hover">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Rut</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre Paciente</th>
      <th scope="col">Apellido Paciente</th>
      <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
        <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
      <th scope="col">Acciones</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let pacientes of pacientes">
     <td>{{pacientes.rutPac}}</td> 
     <td>{{pacientes.nombrePac}}</td> 
       <td>{{pacientes.apellidoPac}}</td> 
     <td>{{pacientes.telefonoPac}}</td> 
     <td>{{pacientes.direccionPac}}</td> 
     <td>
   <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" href="#updatePaciente" data-toggle="modal"  (click)="examenClicked(pacientes)">Editar</button>  
   <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delete(pacientes)">Borrar</button>
     </td>    
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This isn't a material table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a material table, you need to provide our own input field and a custom function to filter our data to use `MatTableDataSource`’s filter property as mentioned [here](https://code-maze.com/angular-material-table/#filterfunctionality).

**Example**

```
<div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="40%">
    <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="filterTable($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Write the following function in the `component` file:

```
public filterTable = (value: string) => {
    this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
  }
```